# Check if it not available in li list, append a something one time only

Tags: jquery, html

I want to know how to append something if it is not available in li list. I already tried using if condition in $.each loop but it is append every not match points.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

Example

There are `aa, bb, cc, dd` and so on text values. If I check `aa` text value and not available in li list, append `<b>No</b>` tag to div only one.

When i use $.each with if condition it is check fist li and it is available aa but Append every li values after fist li because others li values are not aa.

I want to check all li values and if one of li tags not have this aa value, return append `<b>No</b>` only one.

JQuery Code:

```
var findv = $("li");

        $(findv).each(function(){
            if(findv.text()=="aa"){

            }           
            else{
                list.append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;">'+val.text+'</a>');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple function should be able to do that.  I created a results element to hold that result as your intent there was not fully clear but you should be able to build from this.  Note I put extra text in there so you could see the Found/Not Found conditions.

```js
function testValue(checkValue) {
  var isInList = !!$('.ioptionlist').find('.ioption').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == checkValue;
  }).length;
  if (!isInList) {
    $("#results").append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;"><b>' + checkValue + ' not found</b></a>');
  } else {
    $("#results").append('<b>'+checkValue+' found</b>');
  }
}
$(function() {
  testValue("rr");// will not find this
  testValue("aa");// finds this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ioptionlist">
  <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
<div id="results">howdy

</div>
```

Note that this tests the text and if you add more text on an `li` item it will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var findv = $("li");
var check = false;
$(findv).each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() != "aa") {
    check = true;
  }
});

if (check) {
  $(".showMessage").html('<b>No</b>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showMessage"></div>
<ul class="ioptionlist">
  <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want NO not all time i want only one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick jQuery-less version with annotations.

```js
// Default query
var query = 'aa';
var result = false;

// Grab each LI in the dom
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach( function(index, el){
  
  // Check each li to see if a value does
  // not match aa
  if (el.text !== query) {
    // we found a li without aa
    result = true
  }
  
});

// If query was true, then let's append <b>No</b> to the 
// results div
if (result) {
  var domNode = document.createElement('b');
  domNode.innerHTML = 'NO';
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(domNode);
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>

<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```